# ANR error while starting new Activity

Tags: android, multithreading, countdowntimer

Basically I've got a Menu-class with a start button that starts a new Game Activity within a Thread.

In the Game class I've got instantiated a Count-object (which extends CountDownTimer).

When starting the Game Activity I get an ANR error and I believe it is caused by the timer, since I've commented it out and it works perfectly fine. Frankly I do not know how to solve this; I've tried different approaches but failed.
**Edited code** **Logcat at the end**

```
public class Menu extends Activity {

    Button start, highscores, exit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {

        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                        startActivity(new Intent("net.fb.clauz.GAME"));

                };

        });

        highscores = (Button) findViewById(R.id.highscores);
        highscores.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }
}



public class Game extends Activity {

    Button button;
    TextView score;
    public static TextView timeleft;
    int x = 0;
    public Counter count;
    public static boolean running=true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        count = new Counter(30000, 1000);
        timeleft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeleftTitle);

        gameThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (running) {
                    addListenerOnButton();
                    count.start();
                }
            }
        });
        gameThread.start();
    }


    private void addListenerOnButton() {

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                x++;
                score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
                score.setText(String.valueOf(x));

            }

        });

    }
}



public class Counter extends CountDownTimer{

    public Counter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Game.running = false; // stop the game

        //need to implement action to return to the buttons menu.
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Game.timeleft.setText("Left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        System.out.println(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
08-23 11:00:02.963: W/ActivityManager(885): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{b4ca99d0 net.fb.clauz/.Game}

08-23 11:00:18.343: D/dalvikvm(14424): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3397K, 28% free 9419K/12935K, paused 4ms+4ms

08-23 11:00:21.383: I/InputDispatcher(885): Application is not responding: Window{b4cd2aa8 net.fb.clauz/net.fb.clauz.Game paused=false}.  5005.6ms since event, 5004.9ms since wait started

08-23 11:00:21.383: I/WindowManager(885): Input event dispatching timed out sending to net.fb.clauz/net.fb.clauz.Game

08-23 11:00:21.415: I/Process(885): Sending signal. PID: 14424 SIG: 3

08-23 11:00:21.415: I/dalvikvm(14424): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3

08-23 11:00:21.443: I/dalvikvm(14424): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

08-23 11:00:21.443: I/Process(885): Sending signal. PID: 885 SIG: 3

08-23 11:00:21.443: I/dalvikvm(885): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3

08-23 11:00:21.593: I/dalvikvm(885): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

08-23 11:00:21.593: I/Process(885): Sending signal. PID: 944 SIG: 3

08-23 11:00:21.593: I/dalvikvm(944): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3

08-23 11:00:21.634: I/dalvikvm(944): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

08-23 11:00:21.634: I/Process(885): Sending signal. PID: 976 SIG: 3

08-23 11:00:21.634: I/dalvikvm(976): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3

08-23 11:00:21.673: I/dalvikvm(976): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

08-23 11:00:22.463: D/dalvikvm(885): GC_CONCURRENT freed 472K, 14% free 11275K/13063K, paused 6ms+0ms

08-23 11:00:23.293: D/dalvikvm(885): GC_EXPLICIT freed 326K, 14% free 11328K/13063K, paused 6ms+9ms

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885): ANR in net.fb.clauz (net.fb.clauz/.Game)

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885): Load: 1.54 / 0.86 / 0.89

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885): CPU usage from 11149ms to 0ms ago:

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885):   98% 14424/net.fb.clauz: 96% user + 1.7% kernel / faults: 117 minor

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885):   0.6% 778/surfaceflinger: 0.6% user + 0% kernel

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885):   0.5% 885/system_server: 0.3% user + 0.1% kernel

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885):   0% 944/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885): 99% TOTAL: 97% user + 1.9% kernel

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885): CPU usage from 1917ms to 2519ms later:

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885):   92% 14424/net.fb.clauz: 92% user + 0% kernel

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885):     46% 14424/net.fb.clauz: 46% user + 0% kernel

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885):     46% 14440/Thread-108: 46% user + 0% kernel

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885):   8.6% 885/system_server: 3.4% user + 5.1% 
kernel
08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885):     6.8% 920/InputDispatcher: 3.4% user + 3.4% kernel

08-23 11:00:23.963: E/ActivityManager(885): 100% TOTAL: 95% user + 4.9% kernel

08-23 11:00:24.583: D/dalvikvm(885): GC_CONCURRENT freed 475K, 13% free 11423K/13063K, paused 6ms+15ms

08-23 11:00:38.693: W/ActivityManager(885):   Force finishing activity net.fb.clauz/.Game
```

Comment: I think you are just doing too much stuff on the main thread, which causes your app to "ANR". You should use more threading (e.g. your while is way too much work for the mainthread)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove Thread.

```
start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {


                    startActivity(new Intent("net.fb.clauz.GAME"));

        }
    });
```